# Google App Engine Java Can't Run Application HTTP 500

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, http-error

I have a simple servlet which looks like like below. Ite uses the Google's User Service. When I don't use it I don't get any errors. Also I get an entire list of error as below. I turn out that this was an Eclipse Known Issue but I can't find the solution.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
              throws IOException {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("Hello, " + user.getNickname());
        } else {
            resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
        }
    }
}
```

These are the first errors:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /guestbook. Reason: 
    Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 117 in method guestbook.GuestbookServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V at offset 34

Caused by:
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 117 in method guestbook.GuestbookServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V at offset 34
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
```

Is the problem from the Java version? I am running Eclipse Indigo and Java 7. What should I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a known eclipse issue with JDK7. Please check [this link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/javalangverifyerror-expecting) for workaround/solution.